# PHP How to generate image from Base64?

Tags: php, image

Hello I used to store my images as data. It looked something like `"‰PNG IHDRÂæÉ0†"`. I was able to generate images from this data using the following code:

```
include_once "mysql_connect.php";
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `entree` WHERE `realID` = '$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $imageData = $row["thumbXL"];
    $imageType = $row["imageext"];
}

if($imageType == "image/png"){
    header("content-type: image/png");
}else if($imageType == "image/jpeg"){
    header("content-type: image/jpeg");
}else{}

if(!($imageData == null)){
echo $imageData;
}else{
}


}else{

}
```

That code was in a file called generateThumbnailXL.php and I would put that in the src of the images and the image would be generated perfectly. I switched to using Base64 image data recently and I just put the base64 data into the src and the image is generated perfectly. The problem is when someone shares my article on Facebook, the thumbnail doesn't show up because Facebook doesn't like using Base64. I need some way of converting base64 into something like `"‰PNG IHDRÂæÉ0†"` and then echo it out like the way the above code did. How can I do this? I researched on Google and found little help, nothing that will work for me.

Comment: [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) exists, you know...

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have something like this :-

```
<?php

// $imgData contains base64 encoded data of image 
$imgData = <<< EOFILE
R0lGODlhogBxAPcAA......0zEREAA7
EOFILE;

header("Content-type: image/png");
echo base64_decode($imgData);
exit();
```

and you will see image .

Comment: nevermind it does work but how can i substitute the data for a variable? When  I put in $imageData it does not work.

Comment: @bobby Can you show that how you are inserting thumbXL value into database .

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I just insert the "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG..." into the database. That doesnt mtter. I then get it by using $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `entree` WHERE `realID` = '$id'");
 $imageData;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $imageData = $row[6];

Comment: @bobby Everything is fine from your side . now you have two option :
1. echo stored data in an image tag like this 
  echo "<img src=' ".$imageData." ' alt='image text' >";
or 
2. remove data:image/png;base64, from $imageData and do like this 

$removedData = remove_data($imageData);
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo base64_decode($removedData);

Assume that remove_data() is a self defined function which is returning the atual image data after removing data:image/png;base64,  from data.